# WCF Message Level Security

Tags: .net, wcf, security, certificate

Hope someone can help me on this matter. I'm looking for a way of enabling message level security on my WCF service other than using certificates.
Problem is that the application is used on clients that connect via a VPN with multiple sites that each have their own domain controller and the domains does not trust each other.
I'm totally new to certificates, although lots of ppl say that's the way to go, I don't know if it can work in this environment?

Begging for help :)
Kind regards
Andries

Answer (score 11):

Actually certificates are really the way to go! I strongly advice you to use certificates! It's not that difficult. Actually this is your problem: "the domains does not trust each other". With certificates you will achieve domains that trust each other. 
Here is step by step instruction how to do this:
1) You must create certificate on on the client. To do this go to Start menu -> Run -> type "cmd" and hit Enter
In the console window type: 
**makecert.exe MakeCert -pe -ss My -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky exchange -n CN=ClientCertificateName** (change "ClientCertificateName" with name of your choice)
2) do the same on the server changing the certificate name! 
3) after doing step 1) and 2) both your client and your server has their self-signed certs installed. Now you need to export these certs and import the client's cert in the server's TrustedPeople folder and import the server's cert in the client's TrustedPeople folder.
To do so -> Start Menu -> Run -> type "mmc" and hit Enter
4)To open certificates store location go to File -> Add/Remove Snap-in -> in the new window select Certificates (on the left) and click Add -> Click Ok -> Select "Computer Account" -> Next -> Finish -> OK
  After that Certificates console will open. Expand the certificates node (on the left) and navigate to Personal/Certificates node. There you will find the certificate just created in the previous steps. Right-click the cert and export it including the Private Key. Save the exported cert to a file. Then copy this file to the other machine and import it under the "Trusted People/Certificates" node.
5) Repeat step 4) for the other machine as well - the final goal is to have Client's cert imported on the host's machine and vice versa
Now that you have (hopefully) set up the certificates you have to tell your service to use them. To do so you can use the web.config (app.config) file of your app or write in the code.

```
<security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
</security>
```

After adding the security node both in the client's and server's configuration file you have to add the following behavior to your binding:

```
    <behaviors >
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="your_binding_behavior">
            <clientCredentials>
                <clientCertificate findValue="[The name of the client certificate here]"
                                   storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                   storeName="My"
                                   x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                <serviceCertificate>
                    <defaultCertificate findValue="[The name of the server certificate here]"
                                        storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                        storeName="TrustedPeople"
                                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
                </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And that's it! Your are good to go! For more information about this you can read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/Senthil.aspx). And here is even [more detailed one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfcertificates.aspx).

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it sounds like a good solution. Problem is that I was looking for another method, because this method will take a very long if you have to do this for 100 or more pcs all over the PVN all over a country ;( Do you maybe have any suggestion for me. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something here, if your aim is to encrypt data between server and client you only need to create a certificate on the server, and set MessageClientCredentialType = "None" in your WCF service web.config

There are dozens of "walkthroughs" posted on the web, some better than others. I too struggled with securing my WCF service until I found this walkthrough:

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/05/how-to-create-server-certificate-for.html

Answer (score 0):

i also think that cert based message level security is the best way to go - as with message level security client and server will need to encrypt the message - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731172.aspx   - or can also try MixedModesecurity  - some great guidance here - http://blogs.msdn.com/govindr/archive/tags/WCF/default.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/jmeier/archive/2008/03/27/patterns-and-practices-wcf-security-guidance-now-available.aspx  and http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurity  are other resources for great guidance.